# Laravel Subdomain Issue - similar to craigslist structor (www.domain.com, sub.domain.com)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, dns

I have built a base laravel site with authorization using nginx as the web server. 
Then I have created another laravel instance under the main directory in the original site and added a simple index.html page for testing.

I created a server block in *sites-available* for the default site and another for he subdomain. 
I created a symlink in sites-enabled and when I run 'curl sub.domain.com it resolves the index.html page on the second laravel instance.

When I try this from the browser it does not resolve.
I made an entry in the hosts file '127.0.0.1 domain.com  sub.domain.com'
I also tried 'DNS IP Address sub.domain.com'

In the routes file I tried the suggested code from Laravel

Route::group(['domain' => '{sub}.domain.com'], function () {
     Route::get('/', function ($sub) {
           return $sub;
       });
});

To make the site more manageable I wanted to utilize the sites-avialable/sites-enbaled functionality of Nginx. Being able to take a subdomain offline for updates and not affecting the core site and other subs.

Comment: <b>Solved it!!!</b><br> solved it at the nguni server level using sites-available and sites-enabled. DNS entries where not resolving.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it!!!**
 solved it at the nginx server level using *sites-available* and *sites-enabled*. DNS entries where not resolving.